# Why do Meta reviews show even when none are available?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-experience

Currently, whilst on StackOverflow, if I have any regular review tasks available I also get a link to perform some Meta review tasks. You can see this below:

[image]

I have two questions regarding this:

- Why do I get this link even if none of the Meta review tasks are available? (I don't have enough rep)
- Why does the link to Meta reviews go away when I have no "regular" review tasks left? Shouldn't the "Meta Reviews >>" link still be there?

[image]

I couldn't find anything on this after a *quick* search :)

**UPDATE**

Following some comments, I am re-tagging this as a feature request as per Lighteninger's suggestion. The Meta Review's link shouldn't show for users with insufficient reputation to complete the tasks.

Comment: Is that button new or did I never really look good enough before?

Comment: @AndréKool The "Meta Reviews >>" link has always been there for me :)

Comment: It is already a performance juggle to get that menu and its red-indicator working on one site. Having it perform that trick as well for another site on a per user basis is bound to take for ever. Expect [status-bydesign]

Comment: Yes, it is by design as stated by rene but you can also retag it to a [feature-request] so as to remove it for users with less than 2k repo

Comment: I have changed the tags to be a feature-request